# How to get the duration of a video file that's in Google Drive with Python?

Tags: python, api, drive

I have the video file ID and the Google Drive API access all correct and I want my code to return the video file duration. I know there's the "videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis" file property but I don't know exactly how to use it. Thank you!

````
SCgenericQ = service.files().list(q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and starred=true",
        fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    starredSCfolders = SCgenericQ.get('files', [])

    if not starredSCfolders:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        counter = 18
        for _ in starredSCfolders:
            folderId = starredSCfolders[counter].get('id')
            exactCourseQ = service.files().list(q="'" + folderId + "' in parents", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
            courseFiles = exactCourseQ.get('files', [])  
            courseUnitIds = []
            videos = []
            
            for element in courseFiles:
                if element['name'].startswith('UNI'):
                    courseUnitIds.append(element['id'])
            for Id in courseUnitIds:
                openLessons = service.files().list(q="'" + Id + "' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
                LessonIds = openLessons.get('files', [])
                
                filesExcFolder = service.files().list(q="'" + Id + "' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
                nonFolders = filesExcFolder.get('files', [])

                if not LessonIds:
                    MOV_videoFiles = service.files().list(q="'" + Id + "' in parents and mimeType contains 'video/Quicktime'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
                    movFiles = MOV_videoFiles.get('files', [])
                    MP4_videoFiles = service.files().list(q="'" + Id + "' in parents and mimeType contains 'video/mp4'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
                    mp4Files = MP4_videoFiles.get('files', [])
                    for mov in movFiles:
                        videos.append(mov['name'])
                    for mp4 in mp4Files:
                        videos.append(mp4['id'])
                    for videoId in videos:
                        request = service.files().get(fileId="'" + videoId + "'", fields='videoMediaMetadata').execute()
                        duration_seconds = int(request.get('videoMediaMetadata')['durationMillis'])/1000

            print(videos) 
            print(duration_seconds)      
            break```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have access to your drive file and the metadata you mention in your question: `durationMillis` corresponds to the duration of the video in milliseconds. You simply have to divide the duration by 1000 and you get the seconds.

```py
request = service.files().get(fileId=ID_OF_VIDEO, fields='videoMediaMetadata').execute()
duration_seconds = int(request.get('videoMediaMetadata')['durationMillis'])/1000
```

**EDIT**

You do not need to get the file once more again, just make google drive to give you the data you need in the first place. Just add `videoMediaMetadata` in the fields section wherever you need it.

```py
### your other code above make sure you place "durations = []" below your "videos=[]"!
           
                    MP4_videoFiles = service.files().list(q="'" + Id + "' in parents and mimeType contains 'video/mp4'", fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, videoMediaMetadata)").execute() # This gives you the videoMediaMetadata!
                    mp4Files = MP4_videoFiles.get('files', [])
                    for mov in movFiles:
                        videos.append(mov['name'])
                    for mp4 in mp4Files:
                        videos.append(mp4['id']
                        durations.append(int(mp4['videoMediaMetadata']['durationMillis'])/1000) # read the duration 

            print(videos) 
            print(durations)
```

You can extend the example to other usecases if you need to. Note that this is still not a fancy solution. Ideally you can do much more with good request which saves you much more time but this should work and you can improve on that. Hope it helps!

Comment: Your code gives me this error message: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%27U4%20L2.mov%27?fields=videoMediaMetadata&alt=json returned "File not found: 'U4 L2.mov'.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': "File not found: 'U4 L2.mov'.", 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}]"> What am I doing wrong? I'll share the rest of my code, I know it's terribly messy and there's a lot to improve but I'm new to python. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @MaPitelli How do you access your files? Have you had a look into the python quickstart for the google drive API? Check [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)  Then you can obtain the service and access the files. Note that with my code the file is accessed via the ID, not the name. It would help if you edit your answer and provide the code of how you are accessing your file. Let me know if you have done this

Comment: In my code I can get the print(videos) to return the video file's names that are inside a folder. As I know this folder (18) only has mp4 video file format, I changed the mp4 for loop to append the video's ids in the videos list.